# How to Compile my program with CoreFoundation.dll in window mingw

Tags: c, makefile, core-foundation

I need to compile a program with the `CoreFoundation.dll`.
This is my program code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <CoreFoundation.h>
int main () {
CFStringRef hello = CFSTR("Hello, world.");
return 0;}
```

This is my `make` file:

```
CC = gcc
LDFLAGS = "CoreFoundation.dll"
CFLAGS = -ICIncludes

all: Sample.c
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -o Sample Sample.c -static
```

**Problem:** i'm getting the following error:

> CoreFoundation.h not found

Comment: Move CoreFoundation.dll in the same directory as the executable. and set  LDFLAGS as -lCoreFoundation

Comment: Sample.c:2:10: fatal error: CoreFoundation.h: No such file or directory
 #include <CoreFoundation.h> still this error occurs

Comment: put $(LDFLAGS) flags at the end of the line and remove static

Comment: CC = gcc
LDFLAGS = -lCoreFoundation
CFLAGS = -ICIncludes

all: Sample.c
 $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o Sample Sample.c $(LDFLAGS) i tried with this but does not work

Comment: does CIncludes directory exist in the relative path?

Comment: means i am totaly new

Comment: [here](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/specify_the_libraries_for_the_linker_to_use) some stuff the might help

Comment: i need .h file as well or i can compile directly against dll?

Comment: you would need link against a static lib (possibly .lib ). AFAIK dll need headers for c to recognize the symbols. I believe you might be able to link against the dll statically. I haven't done this before thoough, so not too sure

Comment: C:\msys64\tmp\ccHzvgfg.o:Sample.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `_imp__CFStringMakeConstantString'

Answer (score 0):

I say it should be:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -static -o $(LDFLAGS) Sample.c
```

Sorry if i've missunderstood the question, hope it helps

Comment: Sample.c:2:10: fatal error: CoreFoundation.h: No such file or directory
 #include <CoreFoundation.h> but i am getting this error i really need CoreFoundation.h file?

Comment: Since it's a third-party API, you need to place it inside the headers directory of your gcc compiler

Comment: where i get .h file of dll

Comment: in my case the directory to place the dll is C:\MinGW\lib\gcc\mingw32\6.3.0\include

Comment: You can get the open source repository from the apple opensource site: https://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/

Comment: i need all .h file which is mention in CoreFoundation.h file?

Comment: yes, is this file that are we talking about? https://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-1151.16/CoreFoundation.h.auto.html

Comment: i am bit confusing int that answer they does not mention .h file is require
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711167/how-to-use-corefoundation-in-quicktime-sdk-for-windows

Comment: In the answer you mention, he said that he found the file in a folder of itunes

Comment: now i am getting C:\msys64\tmp\ccHzvgfg.o:Sample.c:(.text+0x16): undefined reference to `_imp__CFStringMakeConstantString'

Comment: where should i place .dll or should i update my makefile?

Comment: try to place it inside the mingw \include directory. Consider using the original version of the makefile, if that doesn't work try mine.